# Using AngularJS, how can I prevent $watch from firing on load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with a `scope`, in this scope there are key value pairs for the element ids and respective values.
Keys and values are auto-generated.  There can also be user-defined default values, which are attached to the window and dynamically added to the scope.

What I need to do is, on first load, add the default values to the form.  If the user then fills in values, the scope, with the key value pairs is saved to `localStorage` - this works well.

When the page reloads, I want to take these values from `localStorage` and fill out the form.  This works for basic `string` / `integer` / `boolean` input values, but fails for more complex objects e.g. option boxes where values are stored in this format:

```
{
"example": {
"a": {"x": true, "y": false},
"b": {"x": true, "y": true},
"c": {"x": false, "y": true}
}
}
```

I've tried using `$watchCollection`, - this works for most controls, however, it doesn't work for controls that have more than one level in the hierarchy (see example).

Because `$watchCollection` doesn't work with more than one level in the hierarchy, I've tried using `$watch`, as well.

This results in everything saving to `localStorage` perfectly - including the above example, however, when the page reloads - the `$watch` is attaching and firing straight away.

This results in `localStorage` being overwritten before filling in the form values on load!

frmCtrl.ts

```
this.$scope.$watch('lpForm', () => this.formAutoSaveService.saveData(this.pageId, this.$scope.lpForm), true);
```

frmAutoSaveService.ts

```
 saveData(pageId: string, storedData: any) {
       localStorage.setItem(pageId, JSON.stringify(storedData));
 }
```

What I need is:

1. to get the `localStorage`and fill in the form with the values set without whilst maintaining any default values unless the user has changed the value of the field.
2. for `$watch` to start 'watching', but not to fire the method to save to `localStorage` until the user has changed something on the form.
3. for `localStorage` **not** to be overridden with the form `$scope` when the form is loaded!

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the `listener fn` is called asynchronously (via [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of `watchExpression` didn't change. To detect this scenario within the `listener fn`, you can compare the `newVal` and `oldVal`. If these two values are identical (`===`) then the listener was called due to initialization.

Instead of preventing the watch from firing, detect the initialization and ignore it.

```
this.$scope.$watch('lpForm', (newVal,oldVal) => {
    if (newVal == oldVal) return;
    //ELSE
    this.formAutoSaveService.saveData(this.pageId, this.$scope.myForm)
}, true);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS scope/rootScope Type API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)